# How to know the count of arguments when implementing backtrace in C

Tags: c, assembly

I am implementing a backtrace function in C, which can output caller's info. like this

```
ebp:0x00007b28 eip:0x00100869 args:0x00000000 0x00640000 0x00007b58 0x00100082
```

But how can I know the count of arguments of the caller?

Thank you very much

Comment: there is no general way to do that...

Comment: what OS are you using? Have you tried to search here on SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *deduce* the numbers of arguments a function *uses* in 32bit x86 code under some circumstances.
If the code has been compiled to use *framepointers*, then a given function's stackframe extends between (highest address) `EBP` and (lowest address / stack top) `ESP`. Immediately *above* the stack end at `EBP` you find the *return address*, and again above that you'll have, if your code is using the C calling convention (`cdecl`), consecutively, `arg[0...]`.

That means: `arg[0]` at `[EBP + 4]`, `arg[1]` at `[EBP + 8 ]`, and so on.

When you disassemble function, look for instructions referencing `[EBP + ...]` and you know they access function arguments. The highest offset value used tells you how many there are.

This is of course somewhat simplified; arguments with sizes different from 32bits, code that doesn't use `cdecl` but e.g. `fastcall`, code where the framepointer has been optimized makes the method trip, at least partially.

Another option, again for `cdecl` functions, is to look at the return address (location of the `call` into the func you're interested in), and disassemble around there; you will, in many cases, find a sequence `push argN; push ...; push arg0; call yourFunc` and you can deduce how many arguments were passed in this instance. That's in fact the only way (from the code alone) to test how many arguments were passed to functions like `printf()` in a particular instance.
Again, not perfect - these days, compilers often preallocate stackspace and then use `mov` to write arguments instead of pushing them (on some CPUs, this is better since sequences of `push` instructions have dependencies on each other due to each modifying the stackpointers).

Since all these methods are heuristic this requires quite a bit of coding to automate. If compiler-generated debugging information is available, use that - it's faster.

**Edit:** There's another useful heuristic that can be done; Compiler-generated code for function calling often looks like this:

```
...
[ code that either does "push arg" or "mov [ESP ...], arg" ]
...
call function
add  ESP, ...
```

The `add` instruction is there to *clean up stackspace used for arguments*. From the size of the immediate operand, you know how much space the args this code gave to `function` has used, and by implication (assuming they're all 32bit, for example), you know how many there were.
This is particularly simple given you already *have* the address of said `add` instruction if you have working backtrace code - the instruction at the *return address* is this `add`. So you can often get away with simply trying to disassemble the (single) instruction at the return address, and see if it's an `add ESP, ...` (sometimes it's a `sub ESP, -...`) and if so, calculate the number of arguments passed from the immediate operand. The code for that is much simpler than having to pull in a full disassembly library.

Comment: +1 for mentioning C way of calling functions and x86 assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The number of arguments isn't saved anywhere, as you can see in this simple disassembly:

```
    f(5);
002B144E  push        5  
002B1450  call        f (2B11CCh)  
002B1455  add         esp,4  
    g(1, "foo");
002B1458  push        offset string "foo" (2B5740h)  
002B145D  push        1  
002B145F  call        g (2B11C7h)  
002B1464  add         esp,8  
    h("bar", 'd', 8);
002B1467  push        8  
002B1469  push        64h  
002B146B  push        offset string "bar" (2B573Ch)  
002B1470  call        h (2B11D1h)  
002B1475  add         esp,0Ch
```

Basically, only the called function knows how many arguments it has.

Answer (score 0):

As Yahia commented, there's no general way.

You'll probably need to parse the debug information placed by the debugger (assuming you have compiled with `gcc -g`).

Answer (score 0):

Glibc implements a [backtrace](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) function. It *unwind* backtrace, arg by arg.

You can see how they've done it in `sysdeps/$ARCH/backtrace.c`. Beware that it's quite hard to read.